# Power BI: duplicate rows based on column value

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a table loaded in Power BI like this:

| Name | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Marc | 21 | 32 |
| Marc | 21 | 33 |
| Jessica | 32 | 353 |
| Jessica | 32 | 313 |
| John | 31 | 323 |
| John | 31 | 333 |
| Tim | 35 | 342 |
| Tim | 35 | 331 |

I would like to use Power Query in Power BI to duplicate rows, where the name is for example John:

| Name | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Marc | 21 | 32 |
| Marc | 21 | 33 |
| Jessica | 32 | 353 |
| Jessica | 32 | 313 |
| John | 31 | 323 |
| John | 31 | 333 |
| Tim | 35 | 342 |
| Tim | 35 | 331 |
| John | 31 | 323 |
| John | 31 | 333 |

How can I do it with Powery Query in Power BI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Here you go. Just one line of code.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45W8k0sSlZQ0lEyMgSRxkZKsToYgsZgQa/U4uLM5ESIMjBpikvCECqRn5EH5kKksAlCzQ7JzIWYCCZNjLAIGhsqxcYCAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Name = _t, #"Value 1" = _t, #"Value 2" = _t]),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.Combine({ Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Name] = "John")),Source})
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe one additional question is there a possibility to change the name from John to for example Alex while duplicating? So instead of having John twice, there would be Alex and John?

Comment: Yes, just change each ([Name] = "John")) to include Alex. You can get the exact syntax by filtering your table for Alex and John and copying it over.